# Is there a regex class of written numbers?

Tags: regex

Is there a regex class for numbers in written term?

```
\d = {0,1,2,...}
```

I am looking for

```
\x = {one, two, three, ...}
```

Comment: nope (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 5):

No.

How would that even work?

- it's not a character class
- "one, two, three, ..." is limited to English
- it doesn't take capitalization into account (should it match "One"? "ONE"? "oNe"?)
- the list is infinite
- even if you make it finite by disallowing compound words (such as "twenty-three"), you still have "ten", "eleven", and "twelve"

Comment: No class is perfect ;-) \p{P} is also a class with only certain elements.

Comment: @CyKon All classes are classes with only certain elements. `\p{P}` is punctuation characters. It only matches single characters; it's a property defined by Unicode; it doesn't match an infinite set (because there are only so many Unicode characters).